# Chinese text is not showing in csv

Tags: java, spring, csv, encoding

I have a data base column of data type clob and it contains a file with both english and chinees text, while opening this clob using toad I am able to see the chinese text.

But while downloading from my application the chinese text is garbled.

Below is my code for dowloading in csv format.

```
public void read(final String outputFile, final String fileEncoding, long Id) throws Exception {
        try {
            template.query(QUERY, Id, new ResultSetExtractor<Void>() {
                @Override
                public Void extract(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
                    String encoding = fileEncoding == null ? Charset.defaultCharset().name() : fileEncoding;
                    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFile), encoding))) {
                        if (resultSet.next()) {
                            Clob clob = resultSet.getClob(1);
                            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(clob.getCharacterStream())) {
                                char[] buffer = new char[1];
                                int length = 0;
                                while (true) {
                                    length = reader.read(buffer, 0, 1);
                                    if (length == -1)
                                        break;
                                    writer.write(buffer);
                                }
                            }
                            writer.flush();
                        }
                        return null;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e;
                    }
                }
            });
        } 
    }
```

Here the fileEncoding I am passing as **GBK**.
Suppose my file in clob contains the chinese text 记录 but, it is showing as ¼ÇÂ¼. I want if I open the csv file in excel format it should the chinese text as it is. And if the file contains the header with some * like *ABC then it should be formatted.

I tried to change the encoding to UTF-8 but, no luck.

Is it possible with encoding *GBK* ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be hapenning when you read this `clob.getCharacterStream()` - that will return the characters using the default platform encoding. You need to read it using the appropriate encoding. Try this:

```
InputStream inputStream = clob.getAsciiStream();
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, encoding);
```

That should solve your problems.

Comment: it is not working, it is giving some different text with encoding GBK.

Is there any way using GBK?

Comment: When reading from the CLOB, the encoding should match the encoding used in the database. It sounds like you are using the same encoding for reading and writing but you need one for reading (to match what's stored) and one for writing to the output.

Comment: Actually while storing to CLOB we are fetching data from a text file and storing to CLOB and we are using **GBK** encoding while storing to db. But while reading from db if we use same GBK encoding then, the chinese text is not showing correctly.